# AVPlayer local video preview debug errors

Tags: swift, avplayer

I am currently playing a video from local with bundle URL.

`private let videoURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType:"mp4")`

here is the setupPlayer method:

```
player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: url))
playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = videoContainerView.layer.bounds
playerLayer.videoGravity = .resize
```

I can preview the video and sound but Xcode generates some errors. After some searching on internet, I can not find anything about how to solve them.

```
2021-01-31 15:56:25.026534+0300 PixeryCase[72428:5712733] [] [15:56:25.026] FigSubtitleSampleCreateFromPropertyList signalled err=50 (kFigCFBadPropertyListErr) (NULL or bad plist) at /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMedia_Sim/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2765.6/Prototypes/ClosedCaptions/FigCaptionCommand.c:792
2021-01-31 15:56:25.233948+0300 PixeryCase[72428:5712809] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600002a1be40> 
2021-01-31 15:56:25.563638+0300 PixeryCase[72428:5712816] [] [15:56:25.564] VMC2SetProperty signalled err=-12823 (kVMCParameterErr) (not a CFString) at /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMedia_Sim/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2765.6/Prototypes/MediaConverter/VideoMediaConverter2.c:7105
```

Answer (score 0):

please add

```
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
view.layer?.addSublayer(playerLayer)
```

A convenient way of using AVPlayerLayer in iOS ,

is as the backing layer for a UIView as illustrated in the following code example:

```
class PlayerView: UIView {
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }
        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }
    
    // Override UIView property
    override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}
```

Comment: I also get "VMC2SetProperty signalled err=-12823 (kVMCParameterErr) (not a CFString) at /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMedia_Sim/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2765.6/Prototypes/MediaConverter/VideoMediaConverter2.c:7105" in the console using the backing layer solution in your answer

Comment: you can refer https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118956

Comment: I think it is not code error. It is data error. You should try other videos